# How to save a cropped image with cropImage() to a specific folder in Flutter

Tags: image, flutter, directory, crop

My code does the following:

1. Picks an image with **pickImage()** (from image_picker package)
2. Then it takes the picked image and crop it with **cropImage()** (image_cropper package)

After being picked, the function **pickImage()** saves it in this path :

```
/data/user/0/com.example.myapp/cache/9930cfca-6eb2.jpg
```

And then the **cropImage()** function saves the returned image here:

```
/data/user/0/com.example.myapp/cache/image_cropper_1924443.jpg
```

Here is my function

```
  Future pickImage(source) async {
    try {
      final pickedFile = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: source);
      if (pickedFile == null) return;

      File? croppedImage = await ImageCropper.cropImage(
          sourcePath: pickedFile.path,
          aspectRatio: CropAspectRatio(ratioX: 1.0, ratioY: 1.0)
      );
      if(croppedImage == null) return;

      this.image = File(croppedImage.path);
      setState((){});
     } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print('Failed to catch image: $e');
    }
  }
```

Now what i want to do is to save the cropped image to a specific folder.
Is there any way to implement this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the solutions is to copy the image after that **cropImage()** stores it in its default directory:

After getting our cropped image:

```
croppedImage = await ImageCropper.cropImage(...);
```

Do the following:

1. Get the application Folder on the phone disk using the [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) package:

```
final Directory dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
final String appDir = dir.path
```

2. Check if the file already exists, then delete it.

```
final File imageFile = File(appDir + '/profile_picture.jpg');
if (await imageFile.exists()) {
  imageFile.delete();
}
```

3. Preferably clear the cache to avoid some problems:

```
imageCache!.clearLiveImages();
imageCache!.clear();
```

4. Copy the image using the copy method which is provided by the **File** class:

```
final File copiedImage = await croppedImage.copy('$appDir/profile_picture.jpg');
```

5. Store the new image in a variable of type **File**:

```
File myImage = File(copiedImage.path);
```